# python base64 decode and encode back not working

Tags: python, base64

This -
`cg4AAAAAAAB7ACIAbQBTAGgAYQBkAG8AdwBGAG8AbgB0AE0AYQBwAEgAYQBzAGgAIgA6ACIAOQBjADkAOQBkAGYAMwAwAC0AOAA3AGUAMgAtADIAYgA1ADMALQBkAGYAOQA1AC0AYgA3AGUAZgAwADAAMAAwADAAMgAyAGQAIgAsACIAbQBUAGUAeAB0AFAAYQByAGEAbQAiADoAewAiAG0AQQBsAGkAZwBuAG0AZQBuAHQAIgA6ADIALAAiAG0AQgBhAGMAawBGAGkAbABsAEMAbwBsAG8AcgAiADoANAAxADQANAA5ADUAOQAsACIAbQBCAGEAYwBrAEYAaQBsAGwATwBwAGEAYwBpAHQAeQAiADoANwA1ACwAIgBtAEIAYQBjAGsARgBpAGwAbABTAGkAegBlACIAOgAwACwAIgBtAEIAYQBjAGsARgBpAGwAbABWAGkAcwBpAGIAbABlACIAOgBmAGEAbABzAGUALAAiAG0ARABlAGYAYQB1AGwAdABSAHUAbgAiADoAWwBdACwAIgBtAEgAZQBpAGcAaAB0ACIAOgAwACwAIgBtAEgAaQBuAGQAaQBEAGkAZwBpAHQAcwAiADoAZgBhAGwAcwBlACwAIgBtAEkAbgBkAGkAYwAiADoAZgBhAGwAcwBlACwAIgBtAEkAcwBNAGEAcwBrACIAOgBmAGEAbABzAGUALAAiAG0ASQBzAE0AYQBzAGsASQBuAHYAZQByAHQAZQBkACIAOgBmAGEAbABzAGUALAAiAG0ASQBzAFYAZQByAHQAaQBjAGEAbABUAGUAeAB0ACIAOgBmAGEAbABzAGUALAAiAG0ATABlAGEAZABpAG4AZwAiADoAMAAsACIAbQBMAGkAZwBhAHQAdQByAGUAcwAiADoAZgBhAGwAcwBlACwAIgBtAEwAaQBuAGUAQwBhAHAAVAB5AHAAZQAiADoAMAAsACIAbQBMAGkAbgBlAEoAbwBpAG4AVAB5AHAAZQAiADoAMAAsACIAbQBNAGkAdABlAHIATABpAG0AaQB0ACIAOgAyAC4ANQAsACIAbQBOAHUAbQBTAHQAcgBvAGsAZQBzACIAOgAxACwAIgBtAFIAVABMACIAOgBmAGEAbABzAGUALAAiAG0AUwBoAGEAZABvAHcAQQBuAGcAbABlACIAOgAxADMANQAsACIAbQBTAGgAYQBkAG8AdwBCAGwAdQByACIAOgAwACwAIgBtAFMAaABhAGQAbwB3AEMAbwBsAG8AcgAiADoAMAAsACIAbQBTAGgAYQBkAG8AdwBPAGYAZgBzAGUAdAAiADoAMQAwACwAIgBtAFMAaABhAGQAbwB3AE8AcABhAGMAaQB0AHkAIgA6ADEAMAAwACwAIgBtAFMAaABhAGQAbwB3AFMAaQB6AGUAIgA6ADAALAAiAG0AUwBoAGEAZABvAHcAVgBpAHMAaQBiAGwAZQAiADoAZgBhAGwAcwBlACwAIgBtAFMAdAB5AGwAZQBTAGgAZQBlAHQAIgA6AHsAIgBtAEEAZABkAGkAdABpAG8AbgBhAGwAUwB0AHIAbwBrAGUAQwBvAGwAbwByACIAOgBbAF0ALAAiAG0AQQBkAGQAaQB0AGkAbwBuAGEAbABTAHQAcgBvAGsAZQBWAGkAcwBpAGIAbABlACIAOgBbAF0ALAAiAG0AQQBkAGQAaQB0AGkAbwBuAGEAbABTAHQAcgBvAGsAZQBXAGkAZAB0AGgAIgA6AFsAXQAsACIAbQBCAGEAcwBlAGwAaQBuAGUATwBwAHQAaQBvAG4AIgA6AHsAIgBtAFAAYQByAGEAbQBWAGEAbAB1AGUAcwAiADoAWwBbADAALAAwAF0AXQB9ACwAIgBtAEIAYQBzAGUAbABpAG4AZQBTAGgAaQBmAHQAIgA6AHsAIgBtAFAAYQByAGEAbQBWAGEAbAB1AGUAcwAiADoAWwBbADAALAAwAF0AXQB9ACwAIgBtAEMAYQBwAHMATwBwAHQAaQBvAG4AIgA6AHsAIgBtAFAAYQByAGEAbQBWAGEAbAB1AGUAcwAiADoAWwBbADAALAAwAF0AXQB9ACwAIgBtAEYAYQB1AHgAQgBvAGwAZAAiADoAewAiAG0AUABhAHIAYQBtAFYAYQBsAHUAZQBzACIAOgBbAFsAMAAsAGYAYQBsAHMAZQBdAF0AfQAsACIAbQBGAGEAdQB4AEkAdABhAGwAaQBjACIAOgB7ACIAbQBQAGEAcgBhAG0AVgBhAGwAdQBlAHMAIgA6AFsAWwAwACwAZgBhAGwAcwBlAF0AXQB9ACwAIgBtAEYAaQBsAGwAQwBvAGwAbwByACIAOgB7ACIAbQBQAGEAcgBhAG0AVgBhAGwAdQBlAHMAIgA6AFsAWwAwACwAMQA2ADcANwA3ADIAMQA1AF0AXQB9ACwAIgBtAEYAaQBsAGwATwB2AGUAcgBTAHQAcgBvAGsAZQAiADoAewAiAG0AUABhAHIAYQBtAFYAYQBsAHUAZQBzACIAOgBbAFsAMAAsAHQAcgB1AGUAXQBdAH0ALAAiAG0ARgBpAGwAbABWAGkAcwBpAGIAbABlACIAOgB7ACIAbQBQAGEAcgBhAG0AVgBhAGwAdQBlAHMAIgA6AFsAWwAwACwAdAByAHUAZQBdAF0AfQAsACIAbQBGAG8AbgB0AE4AYQBtAGUAIgA6AHsAIgBtAFAAYQByAGEAbQBWAGEAbAB1AGUAcwAiADoAWwBbADAALAAiAEEAcwBzAGkAcwB0AGEAbgB0AC0AUgBlAGcAdQBsAGEAcgAiAF0ALABbADEALAAiAEEAcwBzAGkAcwB0AGEAbgB0AC0AUgBlAGcAdQBsAGEAcgAiAF0ALABbADIALAAiAEEAcwBzAGkAcwB0AGEAbgB0AC0AUgBlAGcAdQBsAGEAcgAiAF0ALABbADMALAAiAEEAcwBzAGkAcwB0AGEAbgB0AC0AUgBlAGcAdQBsAGEAcgAiAF0ALABbADQALAAiAEEAcwBzAGkAcwB0AGEAbgB0AC0AUgBlAGcAdQBsAGEAcgAiAF0ALABbADUALAAiAEEAcwBzAGkAcwB0AGEAbgB0AC0AUgBlAGcAdQBsAGEAcgAiAF0ALABbADYALAAiAEEAcwBzAGkAcwB0AGEAbgB0AC0AUgBlAGcAdQBsAGEAcgAiAF0ALABbADcALAAiAEEAcwBzAGkAcwB0AGEAbgB0AC0AUgBlAGcAdQBsAGEAcgAiAF0ALABbADgALAAiAEEAcwBzAGkAcwB0AGEAbgB0AC0AUgBlAGcAdQBsAGEAcgAiAF0ALABbADkALAAiAEEAcwBzAGkAcwB0AGEAbgB0AC0AUgBlAGcAdQBsAGEAcgAiAF0ALABbADEAMAAsACIAQQBzAHMAaQBzAHQAYQBuAHQALQBSAGUAZwB1AGwAYQByACIAXQAsAFsAMQAxACwAIgBBAHMAcwBpAHMAdABhAG4AdAAtAFIAZQBnAHUAbABhAHIAIgBdACwAWwAxADIALAAiAEEAcwBzAGkAcwB0AGEAbgB0AC0AUgBlAGcAdQBsAGEAcgAiAF0ALABbADEAMwAsACIAQQBzAHMAaQBzAHQAYQBuAHQALQBSAGUAZwB1AGwAYQByACIAXQAsAFsAMQA0ACwAIgBBAHMAcwBpAHMAdABhAG4AdAAtAFIAZQBnAHUAbABhAHIAIgBdACwAWwAxADUALAAiADUAOAA3ADIANAAyADAAMgAtAEQARAA1ADgALQA0ADIAMABCAC0AQQA2AEYAMAAtADIARgBCAEIAQwA4ADEAMgBGADcAQgA1ACIAXQBdAH0ALAAiAG0ARgBvAG4AdABTAGkAegBlACIAOgB7ACIAbQBQAGEAcgBhAG0AVgBhAGwAdQBlAHMAIgA6AFsAWwAwACwAMQAwADAAXQBdAH0ALAAiAG0ASwBlAHIAbgBpAG4AZwAiADoAewAiAG0AUABhAHIAYQBtAFYAYQBsAHUAZQBzACIAOgBbAFsAMAAsADAAXQBdAH0ALAAiAG0AUwB0AHIAbwBrAGUAQwBvAGwAbwByACIAOgB7ACIAbQBQAGEAcgBhAG0AVgBhAGwAdQBlAHMAIgA6AFsAWwAwACwAMQA2ADcANwA3ADIAMQA1AF0AXQB9ACwAIgBtAFMAdAByAG8AawBlAFYAaQBzAGkAYgBsAGUAIgA6AHsAIgBtAFAAYQByAGEAbQBWAGEAbAB1AGUAcwAiADoAWwBbADAALABmAGEAbABzAGUAXQBdAH0ALAAiAG0AUwB0AHIAbwBrAGUAVwBpAGQAdABoACIAOgB7ACIAbQBQAGEAcgBhAG0AVgBhAGwAdQBlAHMAIgA6AFsAWwAwACwAMQBdAF0AfQAsACIAbQBUAGUAeAB0ACIAOgAiAFkAbwB1AHIAIABUAGkAdABsAGUAIABIAGUAcgBlACIALAAiAG0AVAByAGEAYwBrAGkAbgBnACIAOgB7ACIAbQBQAGEAcgBhAG0AVgBhAGwAdQBlAHMAIgA6AFsAWwAwACwAMABdAF0AfQAsACIAbQBUAHMAdQBtAGkAIgA6AHsAIgBtAFAAYQByAGEAbQBWAGEAbAB1AGUAcwAiADoAWwBbADAALAAwAF0AXQB9ACwAIgBtAFUAbgBkAGUAcgBsAGkAbgBlACIAOgB7ACIAbQBQAGEAcgBhAG0AVgBhAGwAdQBlAHMAIgA6AFsAWwAwACwAZgBhAGwAcwBlAF0AXQB9AH0ALAAiAG0AVABhAGIAVwBpAGQAdABoACIAOgA0ADAAMAAsACIAbQBWAGUAcgB0AGkAYwBhAGwAQQBsAGkAZwBuAG0AZQBuAHQAIgA6ADAALAAiAG0AVwBpAGQAdABoACIAOgAwAH0ALAAiAG0AVgBlAHIAcwBpAG8AbgAiADoAMQB9AA==`

decoded in python - `b = base64.b64decode(a).decode()`
and the result is -
`r{"mShadowFontMapHash":"9c99df30-87e2-2b53-df95-b7ef0000022d","mTextParam":{"mAlignment":2,"mBackFillColor":4144959,"mBackFillOpacity":75,"mBackFillSize":0,"mBackFillVisible":false,"mDefaultRun":[],"mHeight":0,"mHindiDigits":false,"mIndic":false,"mIsMask":false,"mIsMaskInverted":false,"mIsVerticalText":false,"mLeading":0,"mLigatures":false,"mLineCapType":0,"mLineJoinType":0,"mMiterLimit":2.5,"mNumStrokes":1,"mRTL":false,"mShadowAngle":135,"mShadowBlur":0,"mShadowColor":0,"mShadowOffset":10,"mShadowOpacity":100,"mShadowSize":0,"mShadowVisible":false,"mStyleSheet":{"mAdditionalStrokeColor":[],"mAdditionalStrokeVisible":[],"mAdditionalStrokeWidth":[],"mBaselineOption":{"mParamValues":[[0,0]]},"mBaselineShift":{"mParamValues":[[0,0]]},"mCapsOption":{"mParamValues":[[0,0]]},"mFauxBold":{"mParamValues":[[0,false]]},"mFauxItalic":{"mParamValues":[[0,false]]},"mFillColor":{"mParamValues":[[0,16777215]]},"mFillOverStroke":{"mParamValues":[[0,true]]},"mFillVisible":{"mParamValues":[[0,true]]},"mFontName":{"mParamValues":[[0,"Assistant-Regular"],[1,"Assistant-Regular"],[2,"Assistant-Regular"],[3,"Assistant-Regular"],[4,"Assistant-Regular"],[5,"Assistant-Regular"],[6,"Assistant-Regular"],[7,"Assistant-Regular"],[8,"Assistant-Regular"],[9,"Assistant-Regular"],[10,"Assistant-Regular"],[11,"Assistant-Regular"],[12,"Assistant-Regular"],[13,"Assistant-Regular"],[14,"Assistant-Regular"],[15,"58724202-DD58-420B-A6F0-2FBBC812F7B5"]]},"mFontSize":{"mParamValues":[[0,100]]},"mKerning":{"mParamValues":[[0,0]]},"mStrokeColor":{"mParamValues":[[0,16777215]]},"mStrokeVisible":{"mParamValues":[[0,false]]},"mStrokeWidth":{"mParamValues":[[0,1]]},"mText":"Your Title Here","mTracking":{"mParamValues":[[0,0]]},"mTsumi":{"mParamValues":[[0,0]]},"mUnderline":{"mParamValues":[[0,false]]}},"mTabWidth":400,"mVerticalAlignment":0,"mWidth":0},"mVersion":1}`

I am not able to read this as json. there seems to be some hidden characters in this because when i slice it as string for first 10 characters - `b[:10]` result is just this `r{`.
and if i just edit it as string and encode back, its not working.

Comment: That base64 encoded string is not valid JSON, there are a lot of nonesense characters in there. How did you get that data? E.g. the starting `r` should ***definitely*** not be there. All the `00` in the binary decoded base64 should be stripped.

Comment: Had a text layer in premier pro, exported it to xml, in xml this data exists which holds all the info like text which i want to modify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That data is an absolute mess. The leading `r` must not be there and there are tons of 0-bytes in there which are all invalid in json. To solve this you can filter out those invalid bytes and remove the leading wrong ones:

```
import json
import base64

inp = 'your data here'
data = json.loads(bytes([b for b in list(base64.b64decode(inp)) if b != 0])[2:])
```

Comment: The issue is if i remove those invalid bytes and modify jason, and reencode it to base64, it wont work as intended

Comment: @Prak re encoding it is an entirely different question and it surely works if you properly encode it. The problem probably is that your encoding is buggy and was originally at fault for producing this broken data. This code works for the given data, end of answer.

Comment: yes this code gives json properly. Now i have to find a way to encode it back in similar fashion as it was before.

Comment: @Prak that is not really desirable imho, that original data is nothing that any reasonable program accepts / produces. But if you really want to you should check the binary representation of the original data (`list(base64.b64decode(inp))`) and observe that there is a 0-byte after every normal character plus the leading nonsense. That is possible to produce but as I already said multiple times: that should ***really*** not be necessary.

Comment: it is a premier pro xml file which has this data. This data  contains source text and other properties. I have bulk of texts in csv and i want to replace the text in that json and re-encode back. unfortunately the program accepts it that way only, Other wise it wont accept. Do you know any way of re encoding it back in same structure?

Answer (score -2):

I tried removing the first character and then save it as json and I think it works fine.

```
import json

with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    x = json.load(f)

print(x)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).